# GPS coordinates capturing with Qfield

Tags: gps, qfield, position

I am designing a QGIS project for collecting data in the field using Qfield or INPUT as mobile app. So the question is **how to know if the surveyor is standing within the parcel when collecting data**.
I thought that the solution is to calculate the distance between the surveyor's position and the centroid of the parcel, but **I couldn't find the formulas to capture the surveyor's position**

Answer (score 3):

In **QField**:

> @position_coordinate - A point with the coordinate in WGS84. Lon, Lat,
> Altitude as delivered by the sensor. It is only available when the
> crosshair is snapped to the sensor.

Here you can find more information: https://qfield.org/docs/de/prepare/attributes-form.html#additional-variables

Edit: Or same in the new docu:
https://docs.qfield.org/how-to/gnss/#additional-variables